# Windows service

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have written onw windows service..in that i have logic that is some part of code need to execute on certain time.. my service is running in every one min..

e.g.

```
If (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm") = "7/23/2010 1:10 ") Then

    'execute this logic

End If
```

But iam facing prob that it is considering seconds while running so can not compare above time...

Request you to suggest some other way..

Comment: You have a typo: there is a space in the second string. This will never compare true. Otherwise, your logic seems correct.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming you are running in a loop and comparing against current time - this is a busy wait and not the recommended way of running timed work.

Use a timer in your service and set the interval to 60000 milliseconds. Put the code that needs to run in the `tick` event.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) article about the different timer classes in .NET.

Comment: @amitpatil200 - you do have an extra space in the string you compare to. Is that intentional? You are also not using the comparison operator (`==`), but a single `=`.

Comment: @Leniel Macaferi - got my C# hat on ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime checkTime = new DateTime(2010, 23, 7, 1, 10, 0);
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
if(now >= checkTime && now < checkTime.AddSeconds(60)) 
{ ... }
```

Try to avoid using `ToString` as this type of comparission you can compare datetimes explicitly

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime target = DateTime.Parse("7/23/2010 1:10");
if (DateTime.Now >= target) { ... }
```

So, your code will execute next cycle after the target time (of course, you need to make sure it runs exactly once, if it is what you need).

Answer (score 0):

Would this solve your problem?

```
If (DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss") = "7/23/2010 1:10:00") Then

    'execute this logic

End If
```

Answer (score 0):

i have done this type of coding in C# in my service let me show you the code where i compare the time

```
 string SetTime = Convert.ToDateTime(dtBackupData.Rows[i]["BackUpTime"].ToString()).ToString("HH:mm");
            int t1 = Int32.Parse(SetTime.Replace(":", ""));
            int t2 = Int32.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm").Replace(":", ""));

if (Convert.ToDateTime(dtBackupData.Rows[i]["BackUpTime"].ToString()).ToString("HH:mm") == DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm") || t2 > t1)
            {your custom code}
```

hope this solves your problem as it has been working pretty good for me. what the code does for me is that it takes the backup of the database at a specific time.